# Column numbers in the Rstudio viewer do not match the actual column numbers

Tags: r, rstudio

I have had this problem for ages. Sometimes I am looking for the index of a column in a dataset, with `View()` in `Rstudio`. I already know I have to watch out with this though. After working on the datasets (adding and removing columns), the column number shown in `Rstudio`, does not match the actual index of the column. Often `Rstudio` even gives me a column that is out of range (i.e. 240 when the dataset only has 145 columns). No amount of updates or refreshing has made this issue any better. Even making a copy does not solve the issue. Does anyone know where this problem stems from, whether there is a fix or is going to be a fix?

**The Issue:**

[image]

.

**The actual columns:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Never noticed that issue because I never use `View()`. The function is actually an R function and the implementation in Rstudio appears to be buggy. Better use `which(names(m) == "Age85_Older_rat")` to easily get the index.

Comment: Thanks. I sometimes use it when I am looking for a bunch of columns which I know are adjacent or close to each other. Because in that instance it is way quicker than jotting everything down. Then I find it quicker to just type the indexes instead of the names (even though I know it's a bit of bad practice to use the indexes like that).

Comment: I have stopped this kind of laziness, because if later demands require changes in number/order of columns it can get quite tedious to recode all the numbers. Alternatively I mostly use the shortest possible column names :)

Comment: Agree. Like I said, bad practice haha.

Comment: I think there is a similar bug reported https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8281 and this is the old one https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5484